# Deriving types by extension not currently handled by XJC error message

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to parse a few XSDs to JAXB classes. I recently added an XSD and after that I keep getting this error while doing mvn clean install

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Base complex type "InterfaceBaseData" is derived by restriction, while this complex type "InterfaceData" is derived by extension. This is not currently handled by XJC, but we are seeking input on this issue. Please report this to the JAXB team.
```

I am using the plugin:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
```

I googled a bit and found this issue was supposed to be resolved in 2.1.1 version.

https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/issues/73

Or at least something that looked awfully similar to mine.

But I am on 2.4. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I suggest doublechecking the app's classpath to make sure an older version of the library didn't sneak in somehow, as a sanity check.

Comment: I checked. I only have 2.4 in there. No references to the old versions.

Comment: Would switching to CXF help in this case?